# Why is research grade ethanol seemingly exempted from excise duties while pure ethanol ment for consumption isn't?

Tags: european-union, tax-law, alcohol, biosafety

At [Sigma-Aldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/) I can buy [one liter of unadulterated ethanol](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/NL/en/product/mm/818760?dclid=CLuHvemp04ADFU_KuwgdoKIHgw) for just 26.60 EUR. This ethanol contains no additives and is pure enough for analytical purposes. Its made by fermenting grain or sugarcane. The solution contains 95.5% ethanol.

However, when I try to buy the same amount of consumer grade ethanol, then I suddenly have to [pay 73.63 EUR](https://www.heliosholland.com/Alcohol-96-1-liter) because of excise duties. This is strange because the research grade ethanol from Merck is about as pure as the consumer grade one.

In the EU [pure ethanol is only exempt from excise duties when it is denatured in some way](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/denatured-alcohol-not-human-consumption_en) but the ethanol sold by Merck / Sigma-Aldrich doesn't seem to be denatured in any way. It is not marketed as a biofuel either. Its an ethanol solution that's nearly as pure as the consumer grade ethanol but it somehow is still exempt from excise duties. Why is that?

EDIT:

Apparently the website can show different prices depending on the country you live in. Here's a screenshot of the prices I'm seeing. I live in the Netherlands.

[image]

Here's the price at checkout. Some tax is added but I don't think its excise duty related. The total price is still far lower then the price you pay for consumer grade ethanol.

[image]

Comment: Your Sigma Aaldrich link won't show the same prices to people in different countries.  For me in the US, it shows one liter costing $67.10.  I can buy that much ethanol in the form of cheap vodka at the liquor store down the road for a fraction of the cost, taxes included.  Are you sure that you have selected the correct countries for billing and shipping?

Comment: And are you sure the EUR 73.63 is entirely due to taxes, not just a cosmetic company who thinks they can get away with a high price because their customers don't know any better?  (Plus, it comes in a cool retro glass bottle with a cork - that alone probably adds another EUR 20.)

Comment: @NateEldredge, I've added a screenshot. Yes i think its due to taxes. Other companies sell the same type of ethanol for a similar price. [Here's another example.](https://www.natuurlijknatuurlijk.nl/nl/natuurlijk-natuurlijk-speciale-ingredienten/bewaar-en-oplosmiddelen/bio-ethanol-consumptie-alcohol-96-zuiver/a-123-10000007?gad=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwldKmBhCCARIsAP-0rfzKrG-uhFKO16AgKddR1U0euXnwCwrLAfAkhuqBKcOVoEhMggGLZ2kaAiw0EALw_wcB) One liter for 69.95 EUR.

Comment: Can you actually get all the way to checkout with the EUR 26 price?  Conceivably taxes are added later.  Or perhaps it assumes that you are an organization with some kind of tax exemption, and will refuse to sell if you can't prove that you are.

Comment: I tried selecting Netherlands.  When I go to check out, it adds another EUR 14 for taxes and EUR 40 for shipping (!), but also has a note that says "requires compliance review before shipping".  Maybe that is when they would add duties if you are not exempt.

Comment: @NateEldredge maybe you're right. When i try ordering another substance like Butanol and then go to the checkout page, I no longer see a compliance review warning.

Comment: Are you sure the taxes aren't hidden in the shipping price? Some companies consider import taxes in your country as part of the cost of shipping from them to you.

Comment: @user253751 40€ shipping is typical from US to EU.

Comment: @NateEldredge it won't even show the same prices if you're logged with details associated with a different customer account.

Comment: @Trish Sigma Aldrich hold EU stock.  That shipping could be for hazardous goods within the EU

Comment: @ChrisH that too - Shipping chemicals in non neglictible amounts is super costly.

Comment: Hehe. Reminds me of using the lab ethanol to make gin back when I was in grad school.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [Medical or Lab Alcohol are taxed differently](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/customs/excise_duty_and_consumer_tax/excise_duty_and_consumer_tax/exemption_from_excise_duty_andor_consumer_tax/)

For the excise tax, some alcohols are not counted, as the government (Customs Administration of the Netherlands, Ministry of Finance) themselves say:

> Excise goods
>
> Under certain conditions, you can be exempted from excise duty. Examples include:
>
> - ethyl alcohol not intended for internal use by humans
> - ethyl alcohol used for manufacturing medicines

Those two exceptions cover all laboratory alcohol, including non-denatured spirits.

Also, do note the little yellow checkmark at the end of the shopping item: to buy (and import) that alcohol for the reduced tax rate, you need to prove to the seller, that you buy it for those excise-tax-exempt reasons such as laboratory work and not to create, for example, your own Limoncello by soaking lemon peel in it.

Comment: In the UK, the exemption certificates come form the government and are hard to get.  It was a big problem for small distillers wanting to contribute to the need for sanitising alcohol during covid

Comment: Same in Germany. In my city, there are two small artisanal gin manufacturers. What they ended up doing was to cooperate with a pharmacist who did have the necessary licenses and "rent out" their distillery to them for a symbolic fee.

Comment: In the US, for institutions that have a _Tax-free Alcohol permit_ issued by the Department of the Treasury, non-denatured ethanol brings ordering paperwork, secure storage, logbooks, audits, etc., so even if you have a permit, it's strongly encouraged to use denatured alcohol whenever possible.

Comment: Another standard example of differential taxation based on use is fuel. Heating fuel is (roughly) the same as diesel fuel (for car use). In the EU, the main difference between the two is the addition of [fuel dye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_dye) with the sole purpose of deterring and/or detecting tax evasion.

Answer (score 10):

### Because there’s an exemption

Which requires denaturing.

But there’s also an exemption to the exemption for when denaturing is not appropriate. Such as for laboratory use.

Comment: €26/liter is still expensive though. I can buy a liter of denaturized alcohol with 95% vol for only about €2.50.

Comment: @PMF that is Lab Grade Non-Denatured Alcohol, for which you need to need to prove Compliance that you don't use it for consumption to buy it.

Comment: Also @PMF analytical grades are, in a sense, purer for the same percentage.  That sense is that we know/control what the impurities are. This is probably 95.5% ethanol, ~4.4% water, and <<0.1% other alcohols. catering 95% is probably 95% ethanol, 4% water, and 1% unknown (though perhaps with a limit on the methanol as it's toxic).  Unknown stuff is bad in analytical work.

Comment: @ChrisH And it's Sigma-Aldritch, they tend to be one of the most expensive suppliers of laboratory chemicals.

Comment: @Crazymoomin I normally used Fischer in my last role.  Not my problem these days!

Comment: Any company that buys regularly from these suppliers has a negotiated contract that gives good discounts off list price, often determined via bidding. The public price is way overinflated so they can set prices appropriate to each customer while still making it seem like a steal.